# how to extract only MAC of wlan0 from ifconfig

Tags: linux, cut, ifconfig

How to extract only MAC of wlan0 from ifconfig using CUT(!) in the manner of:
ifconfig eth0 | grep HWaddr | cut -d ' ' -f 11 
And why 
ifconfig wlan0 | grep HWaddr | cut -d ' ' -f 11 
doesn't work in the same manner? Thanks.

Comment: This question is probably a better fit for [the Unix StackExchange site](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

```
ifconfig wlan0 | grep -E -o '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}'
```

*EDIT (updated to include the cut command):*

```
ifconfig wlan0 | grep -E -o '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}' | cut -f 1
```